# How can i pass empty array for specific field in postman (form-data)?

Tags: postman

I'm using laravel framework and need empty array to do some actions, and my request is Post with `form-data`. i dont't want it JsonRequest i want empty array with form-data request. please help.

[image: Post Man image]

I'm trying with above, but its returning `null`, i want empty array.

What i want in backend is `[ ]` empty array.

Comment: What will be the `Content-Type`? Have you tried to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  ? and will Key and Value both be empty ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I tried with `key: ` but it didn't work...

Answer (score -1):

hi you can use null value instead of an empty array

when you want send a array for example you send  **key[index] : value**

for a null value you should send just key without bracket and value with empty string for example **key : ""** or **key :**   in postman